# react-admin this.props.record is undefined

Tags: react-admin

I have an `Edit` component which I turned into a class, looks like this:

```
<Edit {...this.props} >
    <SimpleForm
      toolbar={null}
    >
      <TextField source='email'/>
      <ArrayField source='allComponents'>
        <Datagrid>
          <TextField label='ID' source='id'/>
          <TextField label='Component Name' source='name'/>
          <RadioButtons label='Access'
                        source='value'
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.props.record.value}
                        name={this.props.record.name}
          />
        </Datagrid>
      </ArrayField>
      <SaveButton onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
```

I have another components called `RadioButtons` that looks like this:

```
export const RadioButtons = ({ handleChange }) => {
    const { value, name } = this.props
    return <FormControl>
      <RadioGroup row value={value.toString()} name={name.toString()}>
        {choices.map(c => <FormControlLabel
            control={<Radio/>}
            label={c.name}
            key={c.id}
            value={c.value}
            style={{ flexDirection: 'column-reverse', padding: '10px 20px' }}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        )}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
}
```

`Edit` component renders a list of components related to the user I clicked on. Each component on this list have 3 radio buttons, possibly 3 values, it renders `choices` array:

```
const choices = [
  { id: '1', name: 'no access', value: '0' },
  { id: '2', name: 'read access', value: '1' },
  { id: '3', name: 'full access', value: '2' }
]
```

I'm trying to pass to `RadioButtons` input values, it is a different component than react-admin's radio buttons.

How can I do that? Usually it would be `source='value'` but this is not react-admin's component. Also when trying to access record object it doesn't seem to exist in `this.props.record` (it's undefined).

Answer (score 0):

As per https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html:

> record: Object containing the properties to display. ,  and other components *inject that prop to their children*

So as long as your  component is wrapped in DataGrid as it seems to be here, you should be correct.  But you also need to pick up the record like this:

> export const RadioButtons = ({ handleChange, record }) => {

Comment: I think the problems is how to handle the record data by himself.